# Swift: Search for String inside String and get Index

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I search for a String and get an Index where I can produce for example a new String/Substring with e.g:

```
dfnaseurewruTESTAB=41201243
```

so that in this example I can search for TESTAB and produce a new String:

```
TESTAB=41201243
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do it in pure Swift, which (amazingly) lacks the ability to search for substrings. You have to operate in the presence of Foundation; that way, you can use Cocoa's `range(of:)`. The result is translated from an NSRange back into a Swift Range for you (wrapped in an Optional in case the substring isn't present at all). The lower bound of the range is the index you're looking for — the start of the substring.

```
let s = "dfnaseurewruTESTAB=41201243"
if let r = s.range(of: "TESTAB") {
    let s2 = s.suffix(from: r.lowerBound)
    print(s2) // "TESTAB=41201243"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `Regular Expression` for find your `TESTAB=number` string

> Regular Expression can be `TESTAB=[\d]+`

with `TESTAB` is your string, `=` to find the number after and `[\d]+` is `has one or more number`

For example, in `Swift 4.1`

```
let regex = "TESTAB=[\\d]+"
let string = "dfnaseurewruTESTAB=41201243"
if let range = string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) {
    print(string[range]) // result is TESTAB=41201243
}
```